# Count occurences of word within a list in a dataframe column

Tags: python, string, contains

There is a dataframe column with text and a list of words. I would like to:

#Clean

- Remove special characters (. , ^ *...)
- lower case
- split each word in the text with a space

#Create another dataframe that displays occurrences of those words contained within the list as per below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["word1 word,! word3 word4* word split5^", "other data"], ["word2 word,* word3 word4 word5", "other data"]], columns=['Description1', 'other colum'])

lista = ['word1', 'word2','word3','word4','word split5']

#Wanted result
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["word1", "1"], ["word2", "1"], ["word3", "2"], ["word4", "2"], ["word split5", "1"]], columns=['Listed words', 'occurences'])
```

Comment: Can you include a short example of your dataframe that can be used by others? Then we can try to replicate your code and solve your problem

Comment: can you explain your problem? 
I can't understand your question unfortunately.

Comment: @flyinthelotion I hope the changes in explanations helps now. Thanks!

Comment: @novonimo I hope the changes in explanations helps now. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianDove35 in your example, ```word split5^```  would be split in ```[word, split5]```, not in ```word split5```, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

I have a code that does what you ask

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["word1 word,! word3 word4* word split5^", "other data"], 
                   ["word2 word,* word3 word4 word5", "other data"]], 
                  columns=['Description1', 'other colum'])

# in the word list, split in words based on space
# for each word, strip of special characters and lower
# save list of all processed occurences to res
res = []
for i, elem in enumerate(df["Description1"].to_list()):
    res.extend([''.join(filter(str.isalnum, e)).lower() for e in elem.split(sep=" ")]) 

# import Counter, the easiest solution to count elements
from collections import Counter

# make a new df
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = df2.assign(ListedWords=Counter(res).keys(),    # list each unique elements
                 Occurences=Counter(res).values())   # list occurences
df2
```

Output:

```py
Out[66]: 
  ListedWords  Occurences
0       word1           1
1        word           3
2       word3           2
3       word4           2
4      split5           1
5       word2           1
6       word5           1
```

So the code splits words based on the space, removes special characters and lower cases the words (in this order) like you asked.
I have two remarks: I use the module `Counter` (built-in) since this is the easiest way to count words in a list. Also, my output looks different from the one in the example because if you split based on a space there is no way that `"word split5"` would be in your output. The same counts for `word,!`: using your criteria this will be stored in the final df as `word` since it is a separate word (denoted by spaces) but the special characters are stripped.

Also note that the order of the column is not the same since python `dicts` are unordered. You can use `df2.sort_values(by = ["ListedWords"])` to sort the values of your dataframe.